# Error with Conch when installing Kojoney (SSH Honeypot)

Tags: python, ssh, centos, honeypot

I'm trying to setup kojoney, a ssh honeypot, on Centos 6.3, but I'm having issues getting the installation to complete successfully. For reference, I have been using two tutorials:

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-kojoney-ssh-honeypot-on-centos-5.5
http://bruteforce.gr/kojoney-ssh-honeypot-installation-centos-and-configuration.html

I'm trying with and without installing the additional libraries from the Iranian Honeypot project, but I'm having the same issue. Once I start the installation, I get errors when it starts installing the Conch libraries. It spits out a lot of unsigned character errors, but finishes with:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'twisted/conch/_version.py'
```

I've downloaded the recent version of Conch, and put that in the library directory, but I'm getting the same error. If anyone has any experience with kojoney, I'd love any input that could help me with this. Also, if there's an easier/better ssh honeypot out there, please let me know, I don't have much experience with this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to fix the issue, found from a post on the Ubuntu forums.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=920590

Essentially I just downloaded the new version of Conch, extracted it, changed the directory name to look like the old version bundled wit Kojoney, re-compressed it and the installation worked.

However, there is another failure in that it doesn't know the path of the man directory. I just entered /usr/share/man/man1 and the installation worked. If anyone else has a similar issue, and found a different way to solve it, please leave a comment here.